# Unable to Upload the File using Watir

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to upload the file through running the automation scripts but I am unable to do so can someone help me with these

System Configurations

```
 Windows:7
 Ruby:1.8.7

The HTML code is as below

<td id="fileNameArea" colspan="2">
<br>
 Set up File
<input id="file" type="file" name="file">
</td>
```

[image: Following is the image on the web]

Comment: what does your watir code look like?

Comment: Did you try [`file_field`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-classic/Watir/FileField)?

Comment: @Jeff Price,@orde I tried with @ie.file_field(:elementname,'elementvalue').set('excelfilename.xls'),with these I am able to uplaod the file my concern how to capture the error of the pop-up box in case if i upload wrong file xl/file missing for example,if I say @ie.file_field(:elementname,'elementvalue').set('excelfilename.xl') here I am entering wrong format so it will give an error,how to capture that error

Comment: Just try to not get such error.  While executing, you check that file exists in the first place? While developing you can look at the browser window to see your code is correct.
You don't have to test browser giving an error for missing file. This is not part of your site, it is something implemented in the browser so there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

```
BROWSER.file_field.set("/path/to/file.xls") if File.exist? "/path/to/file.xls"
```

Do the file type check before the `set` method if necessary.